# python array address pass to C

Tags: python, c, arrays

I want to pass the address of a python array buffer to another application or to c function,

```
buf = array("d", range(10))
addr, count = buf.buffer_info()
print "Address of buffer ", addr
```

output:

```
Address of buffer  0x28a3ab0
```

Is this address an actual memory address of first element of the `buf` array?

Is this similar address like in C , address of first element of `buf`?

If not how can I declare a buffer in python and pass its address to c function and use its value and addressing like arrays of C ?

if this address is actual memory address can i use this address in `memcpy()` function in C.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.buffer_info) wrote, it's okay to use it as a address. But think of using [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects) as per NOTE.

> Return a tuple (address, length) giving the current memory address and
>   the length in elements of the buffer used to hold array’s contents.
>   The size of the memory buffer in bytes can be computed as
>   array.buffer_info()[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.buffer_info) * array.itemsize. **This is occasionally useful
>   when working with low-level (and inherently unsafe) I/O interfaces
>   that require memory addresses, such as certain ioctl() operations. The
>   returned numbers are valid as long as the array exists and no
>   length-changing operations are applied to it.**
>
> **Note** When using array objects from code written in C or C++ (the only
>   way to effectively make use of this information), it makes more sense
>   to use the buffer interface supported by array objects. This method is
>   maintained for backward compatibility and should be avoided in new
>   code. The buffer interface is documented in [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects).